# I am getting Unknown method 'Registration__cStandardController.submit()' error message

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I am New To SFDC my task is when user enters the value in input field it should save on my custom object after clicking save button.

But i am getting this error message:

> Unknown method `Registration__cStandardController.submit()`

This is my Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Registration__c" showheader="False" sidebar="False">
<apex:messages />
        <apex:form >
            <html>
  <head>
  <title>RegistrationPage</title>

    <span style="display:block; margin:50px auto; text-align:Center;color:black;font-size:150%;">REGISTRATION PAGE - ONE TIME</span>
      <style>
      div.btnGroup{
      text-align:center;margin-top: 125px;font-size:150%
    }

   </style>
   </head>
    </html>
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >         
        <apex:inputField required="true" value="{!Registration__c.Email_id__c}"/><br /> <br /> 
        <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!Registration__c.Mobile_number__c}"/><br /> <br /> 
        <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!Registration__c.Employee_number__c}"/>  <br /> <br />  
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

         <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!submit}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Error says that you have no action method submit defined in your code. Looks like you are using standard controller, you may want to use a custom controller and define the necessary action

Comment: If you need to call the standard Save method, replace the `{!submit}` action by `{!Save}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualforce standard controller does not have any submit button, It has save and cancel, etc buttons. Refer this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm).

To resolve your issue change:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!submit}"/>
```

to

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
```

---

**Added**:

With `location` attribute in [`apex:pageBlockButtons`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockButtons.htm), placement of the buttons can be controlled.

> Possible values include `top`, `bottom`, or `both`. If not specified, this value defaults to `both`.

Comment: Hi Rahul , Thanks for your help its working now but am getting two save buttons now how to remove one save button

Comment: With two button you might be getting one at top and one at bottom. Updated the answer, please check.